# How to use Revolute - Rotational Interface to connect SimScape motor to SimMechanics Joint

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I tried to rotate the revolute joint of a machine in SimMechanics. The actuator is from SimElectronics, so I use the Revolute - Rotational Interface block to connect the motor and the joint together. The whole block model is as follows (also available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1AVP.jpg))

[image]

But when I tried to run the simulation, I got the following error:

> Not enough input derivatives were provided for one or more Simulink-PS Converter blocks associated with the highlighted Solver Configuration block, for the solver chosen. Implicit solvers (ode23t, ode15s, and ode14x) typically require fewer input derivatives than explicit solvers, and local solvers never require any. You can provide more input derivatives by selecting different options (including turning input filtering on or increasing the number of user-provided input derivatives) on the Input Handling tab of Simulink-PS Converter blocks linked below:
>
> ```
> ...'R0x2D1000iA80F_1joint_motor/Revolute - Rotational Interface/Simulink-PS Converter' (1 required, 0 provided)
> ```

I've tried to control the machine using SimMechanics Joint Actuator, which gives a correct result. The error occurred when I tried to control it with the motor from SimElectronics.

What's the problem with the model and how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions to try out:

- Try removing the Joint Initial Condition block and see if it allows the model to run
- In the DC motor block, try setting the rotor inertia parameter to 0 (as the inertia is provided by the SimMechanics part of the model). See the Warning on the [Revolute-Rotational Interface documentation page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/physmod/sm/mech/ref/revoluterotationalinterface.html)
- Make sure the initial condition specified in the Joint Initial Condition block is consistent with the initial condition specified in the DC Motor block
- I would change how you connected your interface block to the DC Motor so that port B is connected to R, and F to C. This is because your Follower in the SimMechanics is welded to ground, whereas the Base if free to move.

Arnaud

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I thought that this problem was disregarded. I really appreciate your help, since the error is eliminated when I set the rotor inertia to 0. But the problem now is that when I measure the rotation angle position of the DC motor, it is a sin wave, driving the mechanism back and forth. I can't figure it out. Thanks